# How can I identify the manufacturer of my windows?

Tags: windows

So, the seals on one of the double pane windows in my parent's home have failed (moisture and mold between panes).  I want to contact the manufacturer to see if there is a possibility of warranty replacement.  However, the name is nowhere to be found on the window, only the S/N (Googling turns up nothing) and a sticker from NAMI, with the codes;

> Code:ALS Series:280 MST:6060

I can post pictures of the stickers/window itself if that would prove helpful.

Comment: The year of manufacture should also be printed somewhere inside the window frame - can you find that? It might not get you the manufacture name but if it's 20 years old, then you can probably assume its out of warranty

Comment: It's less than 5 years old, from a recent remodel.  I'd reach out to the contractor that did it, but he's a terrible, terrible person and we want nothing to do with him.

Comment: Have you looked in between the panes on the frame, it should be etched in.  Sometimes it's difficult to find.  They DOM should be there at a minimum, so if you don't find this, keep looking

Comment: If you haven't done so yet remove both sashes and check the sides,top and bottom for a tag.Ifyou don't find any bring the sash to a local glass shop.It is possible they may recognize the manufacturer from its appearance.They may also be able to repair or replace the defective pane.

Comment: Do post pictures.  Also are the sashes removable?  Pull them all the way out and check for more marks.  Also check the glass for etchings.

Comment: Please let me know if you are able to identify the manufacturer. I have the exact same situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Contact a builder or building supply store in your area to see if they can help you identify the manufacturer using the information.

If you cannot identify the manufacture, consider repairing the damage to the window without completely replacing it. You can replace a broken latch or window pane, or have a professional do it for you, and this may be more affordable than replacing the entire window. On the other hand, if the windows are generic in appearance, you may be able to replace the whole window without destroying the overall look of your property.

Answer (score 1):

The NAMI information may not be very helpful in identifying the manufacturer, since [NAMI](http://namicertification.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7&Itemid=134) is simply a certification program.

[image]

With a bit more information about the window, you *might* be able to use the [NAMI website](http://namicertification.com/index.php?option=com_namicert&view=insulatingglass&Itemid=118) to get the name of the manufacturer.

Here's a list of possible manufacturers and their Manufacturer ID.

### Manufacturer Name   -   Manufacturer ID

A Window Inc. - 412-1
Acadia Windows and Doors - 317-1
All Seasons Window & Door Manufacturing, Inc. - 353-2
All Temp Window Products - 165-1
Alpen HPP, LLC dba Alpen High Performance Products - 1914-1
American Exteriors Mfg. Inc. (Ponderosa) - 591-1
Arlene Stained Glass & Door Co., L.P. - 1672-1
B.F. Rich Company - 292-1
Changshu Hard Glass - 1547-1
Changshu Yili Building Material Company, LTD. - 1689-1
Coastal Industries, Inc. - 1632-1
Columbia Glass & Window Co. - 792-1
Columbia Metal Products Co. (KS) - 790-1
Custom Built Window & Door - 1628-1
Custom Window Systems, Inc. - 629-1
Diamond Windows & Doors - 1633-1
Elixir Industries - Division 34 (TN) - 1773-1
Fen-Tech, Inc. - 354-1
Fene-Tech, Inc. - 1037-1
Fenergic - 1591-1
GlassCraft Door Company - 1157-1
Heartland Window Manufacturing - 1018-1
IDP, Inc. - 1655-1
J & M Glass Company, Inc. - 396-1
Jantek Industries - 347-1
JELD-WEN Custom Doors (IWP) - Ciudad Industrial - 548-1
Jenkins Manufacturing - 1615-1
Kensington HPP, Inc. - 1954-1
LAS Enterprises - 1124-1
Lockheed Window Corporation - 334-1
MariTech Windows - 1477-1
Mathews Brothers Company - 335-1
Mercury Excelum, Inc. - 336-1
Phace LLC dba Accent Windows - 1126-1
PIVA Group spa - 1722-1
Ply Gem Window Group (Alenco - GA) - 162-1
Ply Gem Window Group (OH) - 1411-1
Ply Gem Window Group (VA) - 1408-1
Qinhuangdao ABP, Co. LTD. - 1608-1
Quaker Window Products - 031-1
RSL, Inc. (NJ) - 732-1
RSL, Inc. (OH) - 1436-1
Sain-Gobain Polska Sp z o.o-Lubartow - 1703-1
Saint-Gobain Polska Sp z o.o-Pruszkow - 1704-1
Serious Energy, Inc. - 1437-1
Shanghai Kinghua IG Blinds Company, Ltd. - 1925-1
Shwinco Architectural Products, LLC - 692-1
Silver Line Windows - 1674-1
Star Windows, Inc. - 804-1
Sun-Tek Manufacturing, Inc. - 225-1
Suzhou Taifeng Glass Decoration Co., LTD - 1732-1
Target Windows and Doors, Inc. - 1641-1
Therma-Tru Corp. (Mexico) - 1574-1
Thermal Gard Building Products - 695-1
THV Compozit Windows & Doors - 1578
Tri State Building Materials Corp. - 1626-1
Trulite Window &; Door Solutions, LLC - 1880-1
Vinylmax LLC - 072-1
Vytex Windows - 226-1
West Window Corporation - 113-1
Wincore Window Company, LLC - 1640-1
Window Tech Systems, Inc. - 008-1