# Can you identify the brand of this window?

Tags: windows

Six months ago I moved to this house built in 2007 and now I notice some issues with a window. I suspect the window is still under warranty but I don't have the name of the manufacturer. The construction company doesn't exist anymore so there's no way of contacting them. Someone mentioned that it was likely to be Milgard but I called them and they had no records of any window in this address. I took some photos in hopes that someone might be able to recognize the brand.

*Click any photo for full size*

[image: Warranty]
[image: sticker]
[image: window]

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/how-can-i-identify-the-manufacturer-of-my-windows

Comment: Some window companies are regional, so knowing where you are might help narrow it. It's a vinyl sliding window? You'll want to find commonly-used vendors of builder grade vinyl windows in your area. That being said, it might only be warranteed to the original purchaser. The stickers don't have much useful information. Sometimes the hardware is unique, so a picture of that might help, especially if there is anything that looks like a logo.

Comment: EcoShield Window Systems, Kasson and Keller Inc, has a 280 series window that looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search of 280 series windows led me to Diamond Window and Door. It is a long shot but might be a place to start.

Comment: Related to Mikes' answer above, the first picture you posted has a PO# 7217.
Window manufacturers, such as the one I work at, typically use PO#'s (Purchase Order #) as identifiers for the quote/order used to sell the window(s) to a customer.
At the very least, you can use the PO# and the window 280 series as reference when approaching suppliers/manufacturers for your inquiry.