# Can I identify window manufacture from the NAMI information?

Tags: windows

All I could find short of removing the window to look for the manufacturer's label is the NAMI sticker information it had inside top frame.
And yes I did look through the posted NAMI list here, mine wasn't found on it.

**Apartment Bldg.:** All Windows replaced mid 1980's with vinyl frame/impact glass.
**Location:** Cooper City, Florida
**NAMI LABEL:** Information ANSI/ AAMA  101-93
**CODE:**  E-207-1
**SPEC:**  DH-R35
**SERIES:**93105/91F/101F/95
**MST:** 4562  (MST stands for what?)

**My Purpose:** Replacement of the plastic slider clips that come on the window screens.

**Function:** Clips keep the screen snug in place when slid out into the corners. To remove screen you slide them into the center and pull down on them to release the screen out from the frame.  Being vinyl, they have disintegrated and broken. The screens now rattle constantly in the frames whenever the wind blows or it storms.  I'm looking to find replacement clips for the screens if possible.

I'm honestly not to optimistic about finding them, but worth a try.

Comment: Wouldn't any screen you pick up from your nearest store work OK, as long as sizes match? For what it's worth, my house has M&I Windows and we have the same kind of screen lock.

Comment: See also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/how-can-i-identify-the-manufacturer-of-my-windows?rq=1

Comment: Impact glass, by today's standards, did not exist until 1994 SFBC. South Florida Building Code; Miami-Dade & Broward Counties, only. The reason for my comment is to inform whomever the individual is that impact glass in Cooper City in 1985 would've been undocumented. Beware of false sense of security.

Comment: Are you saying it wasn't a *code* requirement until 1994 SFBC? Because new stuff generally takes some time to become Code...and easily could have been put in as a voluntary enhancement before then.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you just make the Window screen yourself.  They are really easy to make and I am sure you can find a clip option that will fit your needs.  Besides, if these are contractor windows, you probably can't get the OEM screen anymore and/or the manufacturer no longer exists.

Here is an example screen parts supplier: http://www.qualitywindowscreen.com/screening-supplies-parts-tools.html

Here is an example video showing how easy the screens are to build:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxZHslZduRw