# How can I identify the manufacturer of these windows? NAMI-30414

Tags: windows, warranty

Literally all I know about these windows is the following sticker, apparently designed to peel off before the warranty expires:

[image: NAMI window sticker]

How can I identify the maker for warranty purposes?

I know that NAMI is the certifying organization not the vendor https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/27900/5960  I've tried entering NAMI-310414 number into NAMI's database https://www.namicertification.com/supplier-directory/ without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codes can be checked against NAMI's insulated window manufacturer directory, which is searchable on the organization's website.

[National Accreditation and Management Institute (NAMI)](https://www.namicertification.com/)

**On their webpage under Q&A tab:**

**Looking for a Code
The certification label or mark bears a code that allows traceability of the product. If you cannot find the code on our web-site, please contact NAMI at (804) 684-5124 or nami@namiinc.com. NAMI will direct you to the manufacturer of the product.**

Comment: In light of the OP's edit (seems to have been made after your answer was given), can you offer a recommendation on _which_ codes should be entered on the site to get him the info he's after? Maybe even a direct link based on the appropriate code?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question (to the OPs satisfaction, I'm sure), but most certainly tells him _how_ to get the info. +1

Comment: @FreeMan Both of us (me and OP) are guilty of laziness - make a phone call. :) Actually, I prefer to leave the answer as was, so it fits the interest of more readers rather than a single person.

Comment: On the bright side, if someone else can't find it on the NAMI site with the numbers they can identify, at least the phone number/email are listed here for convenience. Covers most/all possibilities.

Comment: I was indeed lazy.  I had expected to "look up" the number on the NAMI website.  Turns out, you actually have to call or email.  They got back to me within 15 minutes on a weekend with the information, and confirmed the database is not online, you have to call or email.

Comment: From the OP : Turns out it's Ply Gem Windows -- who makes a sticker that falls off easily that does not have their name on it.  Himm.  Things that make you wonder....

Comment: At least you know now :) Thanks for coming back to let us know.