# Window manufacturer identification

Tags: windows

The man who sold my house to me didn't leave information on windows.  Does anyone recognize something on this sticker that could help me identify manufacturer?  I live in Arizona.  I have searched the image and other sites which pointed me here.[image]

Comment: There are a few other questions on the site including [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/14466/43874).  They could give you a little more background, but it doesn't look like they have a good answer for you.

Comment: A picture of the window in question would allow us to identify the type (double hung, casement, bay, awning, etc). You'll probably have to continue to search the windows themselves for some sort of sticker or mark identifying the manufacturer. Unfortunately, web searches for "nfrc <info>", where "<info>" = any of the codes on that sticker don't yield anything useful for me. Maybe somebody else knows how to better search the nfrc.org site to be able to come up with a mfgr. I wasn't able to find one based in the codes on that sticker.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? We're not a Google search proxy.

Comment: I went through the same struggle a few years ago and was unable to determine anything definitive from my window stickers (I did a lot of online searching to no avail).  What did end up helping was having someone from a local window replacement company come and take a look - he had the experience to know exactly which replacement part I needed (I was replacing the locks).  I do tend to like to try to do things myself...but sometimes an expert's experience is well worth it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, your manufacturer code is ALE(TX). However, that doesn't turn up any hits in the NFRC database. (Nor does it follow current mfr code convention.)

Other issue is that this window is probably quite old. (Sometimes you can see a manufacturing year stamped in the aluminum spacer between the two panes of a sealed unit.) Maybe it's time for complete replacement...

Comment: When it comes to window questions, you can trust a guy named "Defenestrate"! :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

According to [the FGIA site](https://fgiaonline.org/pages/archived-certified-products-directory), since you have a silver NFRC label<sup>*</sup>, you'll need to consult the [National Fenestration Rating Council's (NFRC) product directory](http://search.nfrc.org/search/search_label.aspx).

I tried doing that, putting in basically every code from your label, and came up with no results (noted in my comment on the OP).

The FGIA site also indicates that you can contact the NFRC at 301-589-1776 to talk to them. It may be worth the price of a long-distance phone call (wait, what??) to talk to them directly and read the codes off of your label to someone who's familiar with how to interpret them.

It's also entirely possible that the windows were manufactured by a small, local company that was never listed with either FGIA or NFRC and may have gone out of business since. In which case, it's probably just time for a full on upgrade if that's what you're looking to do.

<sup>*</sup>I did try searching the FGIA site for "ALE" and "ALE(TX)" but it returned nothing, just as the NFRC site did.

Comment: Long distance call? That's local for me (about 10 miles away).

Comment: Heh... It was more the concept of the "price" of a long distance phone call. I guess the odds of _someone_ here living in the 301 were going to be near 100%. ;)

Comment: I knew exactly what you meant. Back in ye olden days (when we paid for long distance instead of bundled nationwide calling), 301 was actually all of Maryland + an overlay with 202 in DC - i.e., you could call a DC number with 202 or 301!  Then they separated 202 and 301 properly and eventually split MD into 301 and 240 - with all of 240 long distance from me, and parts of 301 long distance, with some overlaps - e.g., Waldorf had some 301 numbers local to southern MD and some 301 numbers local to the DC area. But NFRC truly is a local call from me.