# Can anyone help identify the manufacturer of this window?

Tags: windows

Here is the window tag. It is from a 2005 manufacturers window and installed in Wilmington, NC.

I have about 6 sashes that lost their seals.

[image]

Comment: See also https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/239562/window-manufacturer-identification

Comment: (You want to find another sticker, btw.)

Comment: If for replacement, do you really want the same manufacturer, if the windows don't last.

Comment: A two-second search for "model 450 window" get us to the answer.

Comment: [This site](https://www.swisco.com/) is good at finding window parts by function and appearance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Lowe's ReliaBilt 450-series.

[Example product in the series](https://www.lowes.com/pd/ReliaBilt-450-Vinyl-New-Construction-Egress-White-Exterior-Double-Hung-Window-Rough-Opening-38-in-x-62-in-Actual-37-5-in-x-61-5-in/999946910)

The way the label has some numbers inverted (white on black) is extremely common for Lowe's products.